# relative placement with create window in scrolling canvas

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

[TK GUI having scrolling canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYk3W.jpg)Can we create a window in canvas, with relative positioning?
Or is there any way to place the object in canvas that could be binded with canvas for scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can put windows into canvases such that they can be scrolled. To do this, you should create a `window` *item:*

```
canvas .c -borderwidth 0 -highlightthickness 0
button .c.btn
# Arbitrary coordinates
.c create window 20 20 -window .c.btn
```

If you're doing this, be aware that it's *really* advised to make the window being scrolled be a child of the canvas, and to disable (well, make zero width) any border or highlight ring of the canvas. Otherwise you'll get “interesting” graphical artefacts when the window goes over the edge or even out of the canvas entirely. Windows are only ever clipped by their parent widgets (up to the nearest toplevel).

Comment: But if i create a window Item, it should have absolute placement. But i am making a resizeable GUI and thus need relative placing

Comment: @sushant Relative placing to what? You're very unclear in how you've described the effect you're trying to create. But here's an advanced technique that lets you do pretty much anything if you're smart: you can bind to `<Configure>` on the canvas and move or resize things then.

Comment: --> I have added the GUI screen shot. to the above question. There I have a scolling canvas having a frame placed on it relatively. That frame have some test widgets and I want when the test widgets goes out of scope of canvas, it should start scrolling. Also I want the frame to be placed relatively so that I can resize the GUI.